# Create token with address and fields

Tags: tokens, nft

I would like to know if it is possible to create tokens that have a different address or id for each one.

I need to create a series of "objects" with the same structure but with the values of different fields, as objects of an object-oriented language, and access it individually.

it's possible? is there any erc standard that offers these features?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for non-fungible tokens ? There is EIP 721 (ERC-721 tokens)

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md

Each token has an id.

The token is your object.

Example : CryptoKitties. Every kitty is an ERC-721 token.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's just what I need, even if it seems to have a lot of complications.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy as many tokens as you want with the same structure, each token will have a unique contract address. The contract address can then be used to identify the particular token among all the tokens which follow the same structure in future contracts. Is this what you're looking for? otherwise you can look into NFTs as mentioned by @qCazelles in their answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, are there alternatives to NFT?